# Building an API: JSON Array also for one-element-arrays?

Tags: json, api

I am building an API that uses JSON for requests/responses. I want to be able to also receive bulk requests, i.e., JSON Arrays.

Right now, I have a solution which works fine if the JSON request is always wrapped in an array:

```
[
{"id":"AAAEEF", "value":"abc"}
]
```

works, also

```
[
{"id":"AAAEEF", "value":"abc"},
{"id":"AAAEF1", "value":"vbc"},
]
```

If one wants to request only a single id-value combination and thus requests

```
{"id":"AAAEEF", "value":"abc"}
```

the request fails.

My question: Is it acceptable for a "good" API to enforce wrapping all JSON requests in an array, even if they only have one element?

Thanks in advance for helping me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to writing a "good" API is to be consistent, and to document it well. Whatever choices you make next are yours to make - if you decide you have good reason to require all calls to your API should be wrapped in a thisIsAContainerObject element, by all means document it and release it.

For consistency it might even be explicitly better to always require an array. As long as you throw a proper error when more than one element is inserted.

Comment: Thank you very much. Does that imply that there a no formal problems with requiring '[]' in all calls?

Comment: Consistency is always good, might even make your API easier to implement. It all boils down to your own choices.